# Installing Linux in Specific Partition?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I've 4 partitions on my HDD (C,D,E,F). I want to install Linux (Dual Boot with XP) in E partition. I want to know How can I? I've watched many tutorials on it but every time the author seems to have only one partition (C) or he do partitioning while installing (something like sda,dev [Don't know about them, First time going to try linux]).

I will format my E Drive. But worried that will it give me option about installing in E?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to install, and it asks you where to install it, always pick "Something Else".  Then, you will be given an opportunity to pick any partition, or even divide up an existing one, and format it.

I'd give more detail, but it's been a while since I've installed it, and it's not easy to do it again.

Comment: Yes, Something Else would give me option to choose partition but It will harder for me to determine that which one is E (I think I've to recognize it by the Gb [Space]). Because it will  be mentioned as sda/dva etc. BTW Thank you :)

Comment: I find it helpful to write down the sizes of existing partitions first. I believe you can also visually look at the layout in the Windows disk manager to see how they are arranged.  Then, when you install Linux, you can also see the sizes and the layout, and usually tell which one is which.  I don't remember, but you may also be able to label the partitions (in Windows), and see the labels.